# Shape of Flattened Layer in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, convolution

If I have a convolutional layer with dimension `(5,5,4)`, *(i.e, 4 no. of 5x5x1 feature maps)*, **what will be the dimension of the flattened layer, if I apply flattening on the convolutional layer ?**

Answer (score 0):

For a simple convolution (ignoring padding and stride), the output dimension of the convolution is equal to input_size - filter_size + 1. So for a 1d convolution with filter size 3 on an input of size 5, the output is size 3. For a 2d convolution with input size (5,5) and filter size (3,3), the output size will be (3,3). Now if you add multiple filters, you simply multiply the output by the number of filters, so if you have 4 filters, then output dim will be 4x3x3, so flattening will produce output of size 36.
For mnist in keras, it would look something like this (note that there is a max pooling after the conv layer):

```
model = keras.Sequential(
[
    keras.Input(shape=input_shape),
    layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
])
model.summary()
```

Model: "sequential"

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 26, 26, 32)        320

---

max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 13, 13, 32)        0

---

conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 11, 11, 64)        18496

---

max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 5, 5, 64)          0

---

flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1600)              0

---

dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1600)              0

---

## dense (Dense)                (None, 10)                16010

Total params: 34,826
Trainable params: 34,826
Non-trainable params: 0

hth.